# Короткий синоним для HEAD текущей ветки на origin?

Tags: git

Часто нужно смотреть хеш коммита для своей ветки на удалённой машине.
Например, если я нахожусь на ветке
`feature/123/very-long-name-here`, мне приходится писать:

```sh
$ git rev-parse 'origin/feature/123/very-long-name-here'
```

А хотелось бы что-то короче, типа:

```sh
$ git rev-parse 'origin/CURRENT_HEAD'
```

Пробовал `origin/HEAD` и `origin/ORIG_HEAD`, не
работают:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'
```

Comment: А так? `{u}` .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если хочется увидеть SHA-коммит той ветки в origin, которую track-ает (отслеживает изменения в origin) твоя текущая ветка, то это команда

`git rev-parse @{upstream}`

Если требуется получить в консольке название отслеживаемой ветки, то это команда

`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}`